# Test vs train data inconsistent numbers of samples error

Tags: scikit-learn

I am trying to train an AI model to learn from an Excel file so I can ask it questions about the file later.

I created this code

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
 
import pandas as pd
 
from google.colab import drive
 
 
drive.mount('/content/drive')
 
df = pd.read_excel('/content/drive/MyDrive/AI Testing/togaf.xlsx')
df
 
 
y = df["Definition"]
X = df.drop(columns=['Definition'])
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
 
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X_train_vect = vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train)
print(X_train_vect)
 
model = MultinomialNB()
model.fit(X_train_vect, y_train)
 
y_pred = model.predict(X_test_vect)
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
print("Accuracy:", accuracy)
```

this is a snippet of the file I am using. There are 27 rows in it minus the headers

| Level_ID | Level_Name | Definition |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Preliminary Phase | ABC |
| 1.1 | Architecture Vision Phase | DEF |
| 2 | Architecture Development Method (ADM) | GEH |

This is the error I am getting:

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2, 21]

I understand that X_train_vect and y_train sample size are not the same. But I do not know why my X_train_vect reduces in size when I call X_train_vect = vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train)

Comment: On which line are you getting the error, and how are you defining the `X_test_vect` variable?

Comment: I get it when I call model.fit(X_train_vect, y_train).

I define X_train_vect = vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train)